# How to find the simplest function that contains a given set of points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I searched everywhere for the answer, but, for the life of me, couldn't find anything. Let's say we have a finite amount of points on the coordinate plane like so: $(0, 174) (1, 48) (2, 384) (3, 1045) (4, 81)$ ...

If you were to put these points on a graph and connect them, you'd get $4$ line segments each of which could be represented by its own function (let's call them $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$).

The $x$ values in those points are basically integers, but $y$ values are essentially **random**. So my question is, is there a way to create a function that can represent any such sequence of points assuming that the sequence is finite? I am not looking to interpolate new values, per se.

Or, an alternative, but similar question would be, is there a way to combine those four functions to create a new function $F(x)$, such that all the given points could be found from it? (It wouldn't matter what the value of $F(x)$ would be for any non-integer $x$.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial?

Comment: This seems like a long read, but it also seems interesting. Thanks

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed. Thank you